# check logic 0 in reverse number program in java

Tags: java

This is the logic to reverse a number. But this logic doesn't reverse the number having 0. for example i want to reverse 70 means it will give output as 7.
so kindly give logic to reverse number having 0. Thanks.

```
while(num>0)
        {
            rem=num%10;
            sum=(sum*10)+rem;
            num=num/10;
        }
        System.out.println("Output is:"+sum );
```

Comment: Convert it to a `String` use the reverse function, then convert it back to an int

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "gimme teh codez" / "do my work for me"

Answer (score 0):

Integer numbers cannot have leading zeroes.

What would be the use case in which such a function be useful ?

If the purpose is just to reverse an integer number and use it as a string, 
then this should do the job.

```
int num = 70 ;
String numStr = new Integer(num).toString();

StringBuilder numStrB = new StringBuilder(numStr);
String reversedStr = numStrB.reverse().toString();
```